# Selecting the maximum date before a certain year

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a table where I'd like to select only the record with the maximum date:

```
ID    Date
01    05MAY2005
01    23JUN2020
01    23JAN2022
```

The issue is that I have some IDs in the table where the maximum date is in 2022, so that is what gets selected. How do I select the maximum date for a record that is before 01JAN2022 so that my output look like this:

```
01    23JUN2020
```

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong date in my output table. Edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.
The simplest is probably to sort your records by descending date and fetch only the first one.
If you don't want rows with a certain condition, such as dates after 01JAN2022, just add a WHERE.

You didn't indicate a specific RDBMS so your exact syntax may vary a bit.

```sql
select *
from YourTable
where date < '2022-01-01'
order by date desc
fetch first 1 row only
```